# Kotlin в адаптере сбрасывается ячейка при выходе за экран

Tags: kotlin, adapter

есть адаптер для GridView
при клике в каждой клетке запускается таймер. при скролле если работающая ячейка выйдет за экран то она сбрасывается и при повторных нажатиях не показывает время. как правильно написать getView?

[image: вначале и после скролла]
[image: работающий таймер]

```
inner class gridadapter(ctx: Context, items_: ArrayList<gridItem>) : BaseAdapter() {
    var ctx: Context? = ctx
    var items= items_

    override fun getView(pos: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val item=items[pos]
        val inflater = ctx!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cnter_item,null)

        val hndUpdateTime= Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        val hndFinish= Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

        view.name.text=item.name

        view.setOnClickListener {
            if(!item.running && !item.finished){
                item.running=true
                item.timer=Timer()
                item.startTime=System.currentTimeMillis()
                view.itemContainer.setBackgroundColor(GREEN)

                item.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
                    override fun run() {
                        if(!item.finished){
                            if(!item.tmpPaused){

                                // тут формируется и выводится строка времени

                                val millis=((System.currentTimeMillis()-item.startTime)/100).toInt()
                                val m= floor(millis/600.0).toInt()
                                val s= floor((millis.toFloat()-m*600)/10).toInt()
                                val mil=millis-(m*600+s*10)
                                var m_=m.toString()
                                var s_=s.toString()
                                if(m<10) m_= "0$m"
                                if(s<10) s_="0$s"

                                val str="$m_:$s_.$mil"

                                item.finishTimeStr=str
                                //------>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            item.timer.cancel()

                        hndUpdateTime.post { run(){
                            view.cnter.text=item.finishTimeStr
                            if(item.finished)
                                view.itemContainer.setBackgroundColor(RED)
                        }}
                    }
                }, 0, 100)
            }
            else if(item.running && !item.finished){
                item.tmpPaused=!item.tmpPaused
                if(item.tmpPaused){
                    item.tmpTime=System.currentTimeMillis()
                    view.itemContainer.setBackgroundColor(ORANGE)
                    hndFinish.postDelayed({
                        item.finishTime=item.tmpTime
                        item.running=false
                        item.finished=true
                        item.timer.cancel()
                        item.millis=item.tmpTime-item.startTime

                        view.itemContainer.setBackgroundColor(RED) // RED
                    },5000)
                }
                else{
                    view.itemContainer.setBackgroundColor(GREEN)
                    hndFinish.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
                }
            }
            else if(item.finished && !item.dnf){
                val dnfDialog=AlertDialog.Builder(ctx)
                dnfDialog.setTitle("Участник выбыл из гонки?")
                dnfDialog.setItems(arrayOf("Да","Нет")){
                    dialog,which->
                    when(which){
                        0->{
                            item.dnf=true
                            view.itemContainer.setBackgroundColor(GRAY)
                            view.cnter.text="Выбыл"
                        }
                        1->{}
                    }
                }
                dnfDialog.show()
            }
        }

        if(item.finished) {
            view.itemContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
            view.cnter.text=item.finishTimeStr
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Не скажу как правильно исправить ваш код из за его объемности, но думаю что дело в том, что когда элемент пропадает с экрана его view удаляется и создается заново когда появляется на экране. В Вашем случае вся логика находящаяся в run() сбрасывается и устанавливается заново. Этот кусок лучше перенести в место в котором идет инициализация самого итема или хотя-бы в конструктор gridLayout. Это самая явная ошибка, но думаю что подобных ошибок меньшего масштаба может быть больше.

Comment: сделал. в getView запускается таймер на работающем элементе без клика. но теперь появилась совсем уж непонятная проблема - в первой клетке время не обновляется "в прямом эфире", только если промотать и опять вывести на экран, при этом в консоли таймер бежит. на других клетках все нормально